# Is there a way to add MultiValues and lists in pydicom

Tags: python, pydicom

I am trying to add a `MultiValue` to a list. But I am getting an error stating that I can't. I have also tried `.append` and `.extend` the multivalues to the list but get the error that you cannot add NaN values to a list. Also, I am having trouble understanding what exactly is `MultiValue`.

The code that I am trying to run is:

```
original_z_spacing = np.abs(patient_data[0].ImagePositionPatient[2]
                            - patient_data[1].ImagePositionPatient[2])
# obtain rescaled HU array
hu_array = get_hounsfield_unit_array(patient_data)

original_spacings = np.array(patient_data[0].PixelSpacing + [original_z_spacing], dtype='float32')  # the error occurs here
```

The patient data is a folder of 1595 folders containing dicom files. I am running this code on Python 3.7 and pydicom version 1.4.2. The error that I am getting is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'MultiValue' and 'list'
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to add custom object to a list. This thing will not proceed if you try to add custom objects to python builtins, as they are different types

Comment: Could you please provide a place in code where this error occured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here: a `MultiValue` can indeed not be added to a list, but you can cast it to `list`. That alone would not work in this case, because `PixelSpacing` has the VR "DS", e.g. is written as string values, so you have to convert it to float first.

This should work:

```
pixel_spacing = patient_data[0].PixelSpacing
original_spacings = np.array([float(pixel_spacing[0]), float(pixel_spacing[1]), original_z_spacing], dtype='float32')
```

`MultiValue` is a class used in `pydicom` to represent the value of a multi-valued tag. It mostly behaves like a list (it is derived from `MutableSequence`) and can be converted to a list if needed.